TypeError: 'Piecewise' object is not iterable when trying to sum over sympy.Piecewise result
I'm coding using sympy in python and I'm trying to make some calculations on tuples but everytime I try to use the previous result in the next result it's giving me the error: TypeError: 'Piecewise' object is not iterable.
The code I'm using so far is:
from sympy import symbols, Piecewise,Eq,summation,Mod

def math_func(k):
    result = Piecewise(

        ((1,1), Eq(Mod(k,3),1)),  # Mod(k,3) does k % 3
        ((1,2), Eq(Mod(k,3),2)),
        ((3,3), Eq(Mod(k,3),3)),  # No change if k % 3 == 0
 
    )
    #print(result.args)

    result2 = Piecewise(
        (sum(result), Eq(Mod(k,3),1)),
        (sum(result), Eq(Mod(k,3),2)),
        (sum(result), Eq(Mod(k,3),3)),  # No change if k % 3 == 0
    # Default case to keep result unchanged
    )
    return result2

x = symbols('x')
total = summation(math_func(x), (x, 2, 2))
print(total)

When I run this code it's giving me the error I said above. The problem is the Eq(). it's evaluating a symbol and when I do print(result.args) it's returning all the stanzas in the result piecewise. Try it yourself.
I need to use my code this way because it's the only way to evaluate a symbol if I do k %3 == number or Mod(k,3) == number it doesn't work it only works for numbers.
I don't want any loops. Can someone show me how to fix this code?

The problem is the Eq() Are you sure?  I would have thought the problem is sum(result).

@JohnGordon The result in sum(result) is returning the Eq parameters. When you do print(result) it should show you. It prints all 3 conditions of what I used in result

The error occur because sum() expects an iterable as first arg but it's receiving a piecewise object that looks like a tuple but it's not. This could work I believe (sum(result.args[0][0]), Eq(Mod(k,3),1))

@LMC Yes chatgpt also said that but I can't do that because I"m going to be adding more code and I won't know exactly which one it will be. When you do result.args[0[0] it needs to know exactly which one you're using I won't know this I need the result to be automatically transferred to the second one.

what sum(result) should do for you?

@LMC sum(result) should add the tuples together then I will use that result in another peicewise

Is there a reason you're using piecewise instead of some of some if statements?

Also, is there a reason your summation is from 2 to 2? Is that just a simplification for the purpose of this post?

@jared I tried using if statements but it's not letting me evaluate Eq() in an if statement by itself. It needs to be in a piecewise. The summatino is from 2 to 2 for simplification purposes

Okay, I just had a closer look at this. This goes back to the questions I've been asking you on all your previous posts: why are you using sympy for this?

total = summation(math_func(x), (x, 2, 2)) is wrong.
The function name is sum, not summation

I've used summation so many times and it worked the same way. Can you help me I tried sum but it still gave me the same error

the first argument of piecewise function shouldn't be a tuple.

What do you mean by this can you give me an answer with the solution?

numpy.piecewise(x, condlist, funclist, *args, **kw) this is syntax of piecewise. The first x is The input domain. ndarray or scalar but you use a tuple. You need to change the tuple to the array.

can you give me the full code  so i can run it please I'm not really getting it.

@user25332792 They are not using the numpy piecewise function, they're using the sympy piecewise function.

There are a few things that might be wrong.

you should use sum() instead of summation
Your piece wise expression should be like this:
(1, condition) where the condition is a boolean expression
The way your function is set up is wrong, there is now reason to have two result sections when you only use the results of 1.  If you want both you have to specify it in the result



I can use summation it works how I want it to. 2. I need to use tuples. i'm going to be adding more code that depends on tuples. 3. I need two result sections because I'm going to be using different tuples for both.


Everything except the sum looks ok to me. sum expects a list of things to be added together and Piecewise is not such a thing, yours represents a single tuple, depending on which condition is true. Also, your result2 has the same result (bogus sum(result)) no matter what the condition is: if the expression is the same for all conditions, then there is no need for a Piecewise. Finally, there is no need for a summation if the lower and upper arguments are the same -- that is just the argument evaluated at the value (of 2, in your OP).

I had asked OP about the summation limits and they said it was just for a simplified post. But part of their problem is they pass summation math_func(x) instead of math_func. It's still not clear to me why they're using sympy for this.

Passing math_func(x) seems right to me since it creates an object that can be evaluated at x, the summation variable. It would be helpful to see --without code -- what is supposed to happen: input -> output.

I thought summation takes a function, not that it substitutes an expression.

summation(x,(x,1,3)) -> 6; this is how SymPy summation (the evaluated form of Sum) works.

Clearly, I misunderstood its usage.
